# Building a linux module - sys/time.h: No such file or directory

Tags: kernel, compiling, make

I'm trying to build an old linux driver in my system (Kubuntu 21.10) with `make -C ...`.
The driver is declaring `static struct timeval frame_timestamp;`

If I try to build it with something like

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` V=1  modules
```

I'm getting `...  has an incomplete type ‘struct timeval’` error and some other related errors.
So I believe I must include sys/time.h with `#include <sys/time.h>` into the code.
But in this case I'm getting `fatal error: sys/time.h: No such file or directory`. And I cant't find a way to resolve this. (The code already had some includes but none from sys/, they are all from linux/ and media/)

I ended up with a following `Makefile`:

```
obj-m := mydriver.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) M=$(PWD) V=1 modules
```

The `KDIR` resolves into `/lib/modules/5.13.0-21-generic/build` which links to `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-21-generic`. There is no `sys/time.h`.

`locate sys/time.h` returns:

```
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/time.h
/usr/include/sys/time.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h
```

which belongs to `libc6-dev` and `libc6-dev-i386:`.
`dpkg -l *5.13.0-21*` gives:

```
ii  linux-headers-5.13.0-21                5.13.0-21.21 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.13.0
ii  linux-headers-5.13.0-21-generic        5.13.0-21.21 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic          5.13.0-21.21 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
un  linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-21-generic <нет>        <нет>        (описание недоступно)
ii  linux-modules-5.13.0-21-generic        5.13.0-21.21 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 >
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-21-generic  5.13.0-21.21 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86
```

I was trying to hardcode `-I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` into `make -C` - this has no effect.
I also tried to download a vanilla kernel from kernel.org: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.13.tar.xz
and hardcode it as `KDIR` - that doesn't help and it's not containing `sys/time.h` either.

The question is: how to force my module build process to see the `sys/time.h`?
Does linux module allowed to link to libc? If it's not a part of the kernel, how to make it available for module buildprocess?

Answer (score -2):

Ok, it seems one can't use `sys/time.h` in kernel module.
I have taken a look at definition of `struct v4l2_buffer` in `linux/videodev2.h` where the `struct timeval` is supposed to be used by the driver to initialize its `timestamp` field and found there:

```
truct v4l2_buffer {
    __u32           index;
    __u32           type;
    __u32           bytesused;
    __u32           flags;
    __u32           field;
#ifdef __KERNEL__
    struct __kernel_v4l2_timeval timestamp;
#else
    struct timeval      timestamp;
#endif
    struct v4l2_timecode    timecode;
....
```

The `__KERNEL__` is defined automatically somewhere in `make -C`  process, so up-to-date kernel expects to get `__kernel_v4l2_timeval`. Replacing `struct timeval` with `struct __kernel_v4l2_timeval` among with some other tricks allowed me to compile this old driver.